# How to ng-repeat over an object stored in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I have a scope function that returns an object (in JSON format) it gets from local storage (using this service https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage):

```
$scope.getLsKeys = function(){
    $scope.lsKeys = localStorageService.get('accountKeys');
    return $scope.lsKeys;
};
```

I want to iterate over the returned object's property with an ng-repeat like so:

```
<button ng-click="console.log(key)" ng-repeat="item in getLsKeys()"></button>
```

The problem is that since getLsKeys/localStorageService return a new object every digest cycle, Angular gets confused about what objects it should be watching, since it thinks it has never seen the object before (which is technically true). The error message is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 81; oldVal: 79"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 83; oldVal: 81"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 85; oldVal: 83"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 87; oldVal: 85"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 89; oldVal: 87"]]
```

All attempts to use "track by" in the ng-repeat fail, as the collection is stored as an object, not as an array (I unfortunately can't change my coworkers code to make that change). Is there any way to easily solve this problem?

The only solution I've come up with is to iterate over $scope.lsKeys instead and just update it whenever local storage is modified, but that really defeats the entire purpose of Angular.

EDIT: The local storage is modified during application runtime and needs to be read by Angular; that is, getLsKeys needs to be called during run-time, not just initialization.

Comment: The problem is that your service is called when the `$scope` changes, but the method is also calling a `$digest`

Comment: Can you just do `getLsKeys()` when your controller initializes, and then `ng-repeat="item in lsKeys"` ?

Comment: The local storage object is modified during runtime, thus the scope object needs to read from it to update properly; I could modify the scope object in all the functions that modify local storage, but that is very un-angular.

@EvandroSilva: Can you expand on that? I saw mentions of similar problems,  but they didn't seem to apply to this situation.

Comment: I'd suggest `$scope.$watch(function(){});` or changing it to `$scope.getLsKeys = function(){ return localStorageService.get('accountKeys'); };` this way you won't change the `$scope`.

Comment: Can you just return the `localStorageService.get()` without setting `$scope.lsKeys` in the function, then?  What EvandroSilva is saying is that everytime `$scope` changes, a `$digest` loop is initiated.  And everytime a `$digest` loop is initiated, your `ng-repeat` is reevaluated, which results in an infinite loop because you're both setting and getting a `$scope` object in the same `ng-repeat` call.

Comment: Returning the local storage directly causes the same infinite digest error. To my understanding, angular digests until scopes and templates stabilize (or the limit is reached), but the template can never stabilize as Angular uses exact matching (===) to check for changes, and the function returns a brand new object every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` to populate a scope object:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in lsKeys" ng-init="lsKeys = getLsKeys()"></button>
```

Comment: I suggest moving this to the controller, IMHO, using `ngInit`in this case should be considered overkill and bad practice.

Comment: 2nd @EvandroSilva.  From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), *The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.*

Comment: @Tom I believe that is in reference to aliasing properties of the scopes attached to each of the repeated elements, not a parent scope of all the repeated elements. At any rate, this solution does not work as it does not see changes to local storage during runtime.